# VBA conditional format range based on another range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, format

Hy.
I'trying to format the cells in a range based on the value of the cells in another range. I want the cells F8:Q8 to be red if the value of the cells F18:Q18 is greater then 5%.If F8-F18>5% , F8 should be red,if G8-G18>5% , G8 should be red and so on to Q8.
I'm using the code:

```
Range("F8:Q8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=ABS(F$18-F$8)>5%"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Bold = True
        .Italic = False
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlSelectionScope
```

but this makes only F8 red, not the entire range.
Could you help me please

Comment: Do you want a VBA solution or use `conditional formatting` in the ribbon?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub FormatRed()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("F8:Q8")
    
    For Each cl In rng
        If VBA.Abs(cl.Offset(10, 0) - cl) > 0.05 Then
            cl.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

*# Rows version*

```
 Sub FormatRed()
        Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
        
        Set rng = Range("E136:K136")
        
        For Each cl In rng
            If VBA.Abs(Range("B136") - cl) > 0.05 Then
                cl.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next cl
    End Sub
```

Comment: But if i want to use it for rows? the range is E136 to k136 and i want to compare it with B136? if the difference is >5%, the cell should turn red.

Comment: Try changing code to ‘Offset(0, -3)’

Comment: And that will make all The cells in the range to be compared with B136 or only E136 will be compare with B136 , and F 136 Will be compare with C136 and so on.

Comment: See updated answer. Compares your range 'E136:K136' to 'B136'